# Drawing long lines (100,100) to (-1e20, -1e20) doesn't work in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having a problem while drawing really long lines lines in html canvas both in Firefox and Chrome browser.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// This works
ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(-1, -1);
ctx.stroke();

// This doesn't work
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);

// This works
//ctx.lineTo(-1e5, -1e5);

// This doesn't
ctx.lineTo(-1e20, -1e20); 

ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Canvas element dimensions are [constrained](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/canvas-size#test-results) by different browsers.

Comment: Hmm, but it can still draw upto -1e5, -1e5 which exceeds the dimensions for chrome/firefox

Comment: I suppose it makes sense to consider an infinite (well, not infinite, but very large) coordinate space, with a particular canvas of some particular size positioned in that space and consuming only a tiny amount. Drawing lines with coordinates in the surrounding space *could* make sense, in that the canvas would show the portion of the line in the section of the plane occupied by the canvas. I haven't found any references about that.

Comment: Yes, my guess is that there is some kind of clipping issue with larger values. Or, there might be some OpenGL precision issue with that kind of large number?

Comment: I found that the line does render for right around (-2147483583, -2147483583)
If we take log2(2147483583) ~~ 31. This suggest that we are reaching the limit of the 32 bit signed integer in which 1 bit is used for sign and 31 for numbers. But for the positive direction the limit seems to be (atleast in chrome) around (3e38, 3e38), log2(3e38) ~~ 127.8 which suggests 128 bits in the positive direction??

Comment: That's interesting for sure.

Comment: [These are `float`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/skia/include/private/base/SkPoint_impl.h;drc=67d90538f11c6b232dbfd716075db52aeb34fd15;l=163) not integers, and that's even though the specs ask for doubles here...